# Can we create new SharePoint Web Application in SharePoint Online using windows powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, csom, jsom

I want to create a new web application in SharePoint online Office 365, using windows power shell. I had created web application on SharePoint on-premises using windows power shell. I went through some links which I got but they are giving solution on how to create site collection in SharePoint online. We need to implement some CSOM code, and by that we can create site collections, site, list, library in SharePoint online using power shell. Any idea on how to create new SharePoint web-application in SharePoint online using power shell. Following are the links that I have went through,

http://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/01/create-new-web-sharepoint-online-powershell/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/24/create-and-manage-sharepoint-online-sites-by-using-powershell/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161388.aspx

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: New web application meaning abc.SharePoint.com , xyz.sharepoint.com ?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want..

Comment: @gautam already answered. No , you can not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't create a new "web application" in SPO. You can create a new Site collection only. It can be either under `/sites` or `/teams` path only.

There is only one "web application" and  it is `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com`. It is also the root site collection.

To create new site collection you can run below powershell:

```
New-SPOSite -Url https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite -Owner user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com -StorageQuota 1000 -Title "My new site collection"
```

Reference - [New-SPOSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161370.aspx)

You also need to install the SharePoint online powershell to run this command.

Download link - [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

**You can also do this via UI.**

Go the admin center. You must have global admin or atleast sharepoint admin rights. Click on New > Private site collection. Fill up the details and it will create a new site collection.

Url of admin center:

```
https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com
```

[image]

**Using CSOM:**

Install [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

After that you can create site collections via console application after adding the necessary DLLs.

```
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace CreateSiteCollections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            //Open the Tenant Administration Context with the Tenant Admin Url
            using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite-admin.sharepoint.com/"))
            {
                //Authenticate with a Tenant Administrator
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

                var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);

                //Properties of the New SiteCollection
                var siteCreationProperties = new SiteCreationProperties();                
                //New SiteCollection Url
                siteCreationProperties.Url = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/codesite";                
                //Title of the Root Site
                siteCreationProperties.Title = "Site Created from Code";     
                //Email of Owner
                siteCreationProperties.Owner = "admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com";                
                //Template of the Root Site. Using Team Site for now.
                siteCreationProperties.Template = "STS#0";     
                //Storage Limit in MB
                siteCreationProperties.StorageMaximumLevel = 100; 
                //UserCode Resource Points Allowed
                siteCreationProperties.UserCodeMaximumLevel = 50;

                //Create the SiteCollection
                SpoOperation spo = tenant.CreateSite(siteCreationProperties);

                tenantContext.Load(tenant);

                //We will need the IsComplete property to check if the provisioning of the Site Collection is complete.
                tenantContext.Load(spo, i => i.IsComplete);

                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

                //Check if provisioning of the SiteCollection is complete.
                while (!spo.IsComplete)
                {
                    //Wait for 30 seconds and then try again
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                    spo.RefreshLoad();
                    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
                } 
                Console.WriteLine("SiteCollection Created."); 
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Code reference - [Create site collections using CSOM](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/create-site-collections-with-csom-in.html)

Comment: Okay, how can there be only one web application. I mean, I am not aware about the farm structure in office 365. So I am asking. Since as per my knowledge, there is one tenant admin who manages the web applications. And can create the same. How does the central admin work there in SharePoint online, that we can create only one web application.

Comment: I am hazarding guess here, but i am pretty sure its accurate. The farm structure would be similar to that we have on standard on premise. However it has restrictions.  So ,whenever an org buys SPO subscription, a "web application" is created and is tied to your subscription. So you can create only one webapp say `tenantname.sharepoint.com` , if you want another one like `abc.sharepoint.com`, you need to buy another subscription. It cant be associated with the old one. This is Microsoft defined way. Even the tenant admin/global admin cant create "web app", they can only create site collections.

Comment: The entire infra is handled by Microsoft, so unlike our traditional central admin, here we have the admin-center somewhat similar but quite different. For example, you cant deploy wsp with dll or monitor & run timer jobs etc. Everything is handled by MS.